# Codeigniter 4 error al establecer claves foraneas en la base de datos

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

estoy creando las siguientes dos tablas:

Table Movie

```
<?php
    namespace App\Database\Migrations;
    
    use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;
    
        class Movies extends Migration
        {
            public function up()
            {
                $this->db->disableForeignKeyChecks();
                $this->forge->addField([
                    'ID'          => [
                        'type'           => 'INT',
                        'constraint'     => 5,
                        'unsigned'       => true,
                        'auto_increment' => true,
                    ],
                    'title'       => [
                        'type'       => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => '100',
                    ],
                    'description' => [
                        'type' => 'TEXT',
                        'null' => true,
                    ],
                    'created_at' => [
                        'type' => 'DATETIME',
                        'null' => true,
                    ],
                    'updated_at' => [
                        'type' => 'DATETIME',
                        'null' => true,
                    ],
                    'id_category' => [
                        'type' => 'INT',
                        'constraint' => 5,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                    ]
                ]);
                $this->forge->addKey('ID', true);
                $this->forge->addForeignKey("id_category", "categories", "ID", "CASCADE", "SET NULL");
                $this->forge->createTable('movies');
                $this->db->enableForeignKeyChecks();
            }
        
            public function down()
            {
                $this->forge->dropTable('movies');
            }
        }
```

Table Categoires

```
<?php

namespace App\Database\Migrations;

use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;

class Categories extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {

        $this->forge->addField([
            'ID'          => [
                'type'           => 'INT',
                'constraint'     => 5,
                'unsigned'       => true,
                'auto_increment' => true,
            ],
            'name'       => [
                'type'       => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '100',
            ],
            'created_at' => [
                'type' => 'DATETIME',
                'null' => true,
            ],
            'updated_at' => [
                'type' => 'DATETIME',
                'null' => true,
            ],
        ]);
        $this->forge->addKey('ID', true);
        $this->forge->createTable('categories');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->forge->dropTable('categories');
    }
}
```

El problema es en la tabla movies. la linea que añade la foreing key esta causando que no se cree la tabla movies. simplimente eso. no da ningun mensaje de error cuando ejecute spark migrate. todo sale correcto pero la tabla movie no se crea.

si elimino la linea con el metodo `addForeignKey` todo funciona bien. pero ahora necesito agregar la foreign key.

buscando el documentacion vi que recomendaban el uso `disableForeignKeyChecks` y `enableForeignKeyChecks` para evitar problemas.

pero eso no hizo ninguna diferencia para mi.

estoy usando codeigniter4.

Agradezco su apoyo.

Comment: No uso codeigniter, pero entiendo que primero estás creando la tabla categories antes de intentar crear movies, y que quizas ese SET NULL que intentas poner te dificulta el asunto porque entiendo que se corresponde con el ON UPDATE, y quizás esos campos no permiten el null. Prueba con NO ACTION u otro valor a ver si cuela.

Comment: Uhm entiendo. creo que tiene sentido aunque no estoy seguro del orden en que se ejecutan cuando ejecuto spark migrate:refresh.  vere si puedo averiguar eso y hacer la prueba.

Comment: Hola acabo de probar colocando NO ACTION y me funciono perfecto. muchicsimas gracias. Podrias responder y explicar mas detalladamente por que esto funciona.

Comment: Como te decía no se codeigniter, pero sí un poco de MySQL y PHP, y no voy a responder pues me quedaría corto en la explicación.  El porque ahora te funciona entiendo que es debido a que el campo no podia ser NULL porque [no lo has definido así](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/forge.html#adding-fields), y parece que Codeigniter por defecto los pone como NOT NULL (mira ese enlace). Esa es toda mi explicación :-)

Comment: entiendo, Gracias!

Comment: Si lo que te interesa es ponerlo como NULL entonces defínelo como tal siguiendo las explicaciones de ese enlace de mi anterior comentario, y dejando de nuevo el SET NULL a ver si ahora sí.